# how to vectorize camera taken product photos?

Tags: graphic-styles

I am a photographer with good knowledge of photoshop & illustrator. This time i have a task from my boss who needs high quality computer generated photos of our company products. he is not satisfied with camera result and needs something more lively and 3d like. I have basic understanding of vector based objects but i do not know how to achieve images like this:

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/aplus/detail-page/Scott_ExtraSoftMR12Pack_B00AYV59WY_img1_lg.jpg]

[image]

Can somebody explain to me how can we draw images like this, and which tools are needed for that. I am also unsure whether these images are vectorized from camera taken photos.

Comment: Those are most likely 3D renders, not vectors.

Comment: Can I ask why the photos aren't 3D like? It might be a lot easier to teach you how to improve photos then to start all over with illustration or modeling+rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your company products you have your company artwork. You do not vectorize a photo of your own products, you use the original artwork. You either:

**1)** Generate a pure 3D render from scrach and prepare the materials accordingly to the 3D object (unwrap it)
https://www.blender.org/

**2)** Use some mockups, in this case a pile of toilet paper, and morph your original artwork to fit the perspective and add some shadows.
You can use Ilustrator or Photoshop. Probably Photoshop in this case.

It is a simple matter of adding perspective and a bit of deformation on the sides. http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/photoshop/how-to-use-puppet-warp-in-photoshop-cs6/

Answer (score -4):

1. Logos need to be vectorized - [vectorization.eu](http://www.vectorization.eu/)
2. 3D models can be done in Cinema4D - [maxon.net](http://www.maxon.net/en/)

Comment: your answer looks very spammy and you don't provide any info on your affiliation with the link. Please take a look at the [help] if you need to know more about the site.